# Trouble Deploying Grails Application After Upgrading to Ver. 5.1.2 in Tomcat Server

Tags: grails, build.gradle, grails-orm, tomcat9, grails-5

Not sure why I'm  getting this error while i deploy on tomcat server and i see its trying to find some yml file but i dont see any file on my code

I'm confused where to start trying various scenarios and still could not able to replicate the issue and solve it

```
ERROR --- [   NO_USER] [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig   : Error deploying web application archive [E:\Tomcat\webapps\smp##build-533.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/smp##build-533]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException: Config data resource 'file [E:\smp-config.yml]' via location 'E:\smp-config.yml' cannot be found
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.withLocation(ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.handle(ConfigDataImporter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5211)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I'm having trouble deploying application after upgrading to grails 5 from 3 made all the necessary config changes. I dont see any issue while running application locally but i see the error as above while deploying not sure what am missing.

Please help me in this

Comment: From the error logs, it looks like the file `E:\smp-config.yml` is not present on the server.

Comment: Before upgrading grails from 3 to 5 that file is not present even. why it didn't throw an error at that time and its throwing an error now after upgrading

Comment: This behavior may have changed in the Spring Boot version shipped with Grails 5.

Comment: can you please help me resolve this issue i have added grails.plugin.auditLog.auditDomainClassName = 'smp.AuditLogEvent'
 this property in application.groovy file still i see the error as Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please configure auditLog.auditDomainClassName in Config.groovy

Comment: To be honest, I am currently super busy with other items on my plate and it is difficult to help without a sample application. I would suggest you to set breakpoints at `IllegalArgumentException` which might help figuring out why you are facing challenges.